# Evaluating a Polynomial over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

When we have a polynomial over a ring, then the co-efficients of the polynomial belong to the ring i.e. they are all mod some number. For example, $f(x) = x^3 − 3x^2 + 2x$ over $\mathbb Z_7$

However, is the modulo relevant at all when we evaluate the polynomial for some $x$?

For example, we want to evaluate $f$ at $x=7$, would $f(7)$ evaluate to $$(7^3 - 3*(7^2) + 2*7) = 210$$ or would it evaluate to $$210 \bmod 7 = 0?$$

Comment: A polynomial $f$ comes / should come with its ring of definition. It looks like in the example we are working over the ring (even field) $\Bbb F_7\cong \Bbb Z/7$ with seven elements. Then the function $x\to f(x)$ from the ring into itself is well defined. Above, one should say $f(7\pmod(7))=210\pmod7$, and of course one can compute easier $f(7\pmod7)=f(0\pmod7)=0\pmod7$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The polynomial is evaluated within the ring over which it is defined.

So, if $f\in R[X]$, this means that, for $x\in R$, you have $f(x)\in R$.

This means that, in your particular case, you can very quickly evaluate $f(7)$ because

$$f(7)=f(0)=0^3-3\cdot 0^2+2\cdot 0 = 0.$$

That said, it is also perfectly true to say $f(7)=210$, because in the ring $\mathbb Z_7$, $210$ and $0$ denote the same element.

---

Tiny note: in the context of the ring $\mathbb Z_7$, neither "$210$" nor "$0$" denote the **numbers** $210$ and $0$, respectively. They denote *equivalence classes* (well, actually, one equivalence class), and the numbers $210$ and $0$ are elements of those equivalence class.